# Type of RHS operand in bitwise shift of unsigned types

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift, performance

I want to shift an unsigned type (e.g. size_t) by a non-negative number of (binary) digits / places to the left/right, e.g.

```
size_t x;
x << non_const_expr
```

under the assumptions that the value of `non_const_expr` fits in an `(unsigned) int` and `never` causes undefined behavior (its value is non-negative and does not exceed the number of digits in `x`). (Note that the value is unknown at compile-time.)

Suppose that such a shift occurs in a performance-critical section (e.g. it is the only operation in the innermost loop). My trilemma is which type the right operand (the return type of `non_consts_expr`) should ideally be for the fastest shift operation:

- `unsigned int` seems most readable/intuitive)
- `int` (AFAIK `int` is the native (and fastest?) type on the platform, while `unsigned` could be implemented in a less efficient manner`)
- the type of the LHS in the shift operation (i.e. `size_t` in this case)

Does it matter at all? If yes, which one *generally* results in the fastest code?

Comment: You could always use `std::uint_fast32_t` if you're worried about the performance of unsigned int types and that should give you a fast one.

Comment: I don't think it matters. Do you have any evidence that this shift instruction is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Confident that since the shift is only defined for say 0 to 31 (given 32-bit `x`) and anything else is UB, _most_ (weasel words) will simple use the 5 LSbits of `non_const_expr` regardless of its type.

Comment: The LHS integer type that matches the CPU native size is certainly not slower than anything else.  I.e. Fastest, although other types may be equally fast.

Comment: Note: Many processors, by design, do not shift by the count, but rather by X LSBits of the count.  BITD, the 8088 would shift a 16-bit `int` based on the 8 LSBits of the count.  Each shift took 1 cycle.  So if the count was foolishly 255, this instruction take a _long_ time.  Thus creating a huge worse-case latency time for interrupts.  Intel wisely used the 4 (or 5) LSBits for subsequent processors.

Comment: My main fears are that if I choose an inappropriate type, the compiler could generate extra checks/instructions that would have not been generated otherwise. For example, a compiler might be too smart and make negative shifts well-defined by inserting additional assembly code, so making RHS unsigned would eliminate that attempt, perhaps.

Comment: A (signed) int allows for negative shifting amounts, which is undefined behavior on most platforms.

Comment: @OP, is the `non_const_expr` the same value inside the "performance-critical section"?  If so, call code that uses a fixed shift.  `if (non_const_expr==5) for(i=n; i>0; i--) { foo1(); x << 5; foo2(); }`.  Somehow, at the end of the day, just can't see optimizing this shift will make any significant difference in speed.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal performance of a left or right shift is when the RHS is a positive numerical constant.

Otherwise, it's processor dependent.

I suggest you code up different examples and look at the assembly language code generated by the compiler.  You may also want to adjust the optimization settings also to see if they have any influence.

On the ARM7 processor, a shift operation may occur with a load register instruction; otherwise it would load a value then use a shift assembly instruction.

If you use a variable for the RHS, you are looking at the minimal operations:

1. Load RHS from memory.
2. Shift the register holding the LHS value by the RHS value.
3. Store Result into memory.

The truth will be in the assembly language listing.

Optimizations at this level often don't produce negligible performance gains.  Usually bigger gains can be found by optimizing design or code elsewhere.